# Canonical way to check file size in Windows API?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is there a canonical way to check the size of a file in Windows?  Googling brings me both [Find­First­File](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx) and [GetFileSizeEx](http://www.flamingspork.com/blog/2008/02/11/getting-a-file-size-on-windows/) but no clear winner. And must GetLastError always be called too?

Comment: [MSDN answers your second question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the size, the `GetFileSizeEx` is the clear winner. Yes, `FindFirstFile` will do the job too, but it's really intended for other purposes, and unless you need to do those other things, its use is likely to mislead or confuse the reader.